# Triple Integral of region bounded by cylinder $x^2 + 3z^2 = 9$ and the planes $y = 0$ and $x + y = 3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5DsG.png) is the questoin with a diagram.

My attempt at solution:

$$x^2 + 3z^2 = 9 \Rightarrow 3z^z = 9-x^2 \Rightarrow z^2 = 3 - \frac{x^2}{3} $$
$$\Rightarrow -\sqrt{3 - \frac{x^2}{3}} \leq z \leq \sqrt{3 - \frac{x^2}{3}}  $$
$$x = y - 3, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ y = 0$$

From here on I don't know how to proceed and figure out the bounds and I would appreciate any hints.

My other question is what are some general techniques to figure out the bounds of areas for evaluating double and triple integrals? My problem is that I don't know what the graphs of the function look like and a lot of solutions I see online are where people are visualizing the graphs and using the graphs to figure out the region. For example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkVGT.png) my professor gives a solution for a question where we had to change the order of integration and he's using the facts "W describes unit sphere", "hence we have projection into xy plane" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, the cylinder is bounded below by $y=0$ and above by the plane $y=3-x$. The region in the $xz$-plane is an ellipse given by $x^+3z^2=9$ with a major axis on the $x$-axis, then, the volume is given by

> $$V =  \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-\sqrt{9-3z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-3z^2}}\int_{0}^{3-x}dydxdz=4 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-3z^2}}\int_{0}^{3-x}dydxdz .$$

or you can do it in the other order

> $$ V := \int\int\int dy\,dz\, dx $$.

Comment: Okay, I understand now how you got the limits of integration but how did you know that

$$V =  \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-\sqrt{9-3z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-3z^2}}\int_{0}^{3-x}dydxdz=4 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-3z^2}}\int_{0}^{3-x}dydxdz .$$